# Writing a 36 bit random number generator

Tags: algorithm, math, random

I'm writing an application in an environment that features

- 36 bit one's complement integers
- arithmetic limited to `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and remainder
- no bit operations like `AND` or `OR`. But because of one's complement, `XOR` is equivalent to subtraction and `NOT` to negation.
- numeric overflow is fatal, so can't be used for silent truncation
- Yes, there are conditionals: `IF/THEN/ELSEIF/ELSE/IF`.

Ideally, I'd like 35 or 36 bit random integers, but 25 bits would suffice too.

My naive implementations of the [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) run into overflow if based on sufficiently large numbers and produce only a small number of bits when I use smaller numbers.

So I'm looking either for a set of numbers *a,c,m* that will yield the maximum number of bits in the constraints, or a sensible adaptation of the LCG to combine 2 or more numbers.

As a starting point, here's what I'm using so far:

```
*DEFINE NextRandom . min,max resultVar
* . This is a very shitty RNG. The numbers were never checked
* . for suitability for a long-period linear congruential generator.
* . But it yields numbers that look vaguely random.
*CLEAR rq
*CLEAR rr
*SET RandZ = RandZ * 169687 + 347011      . RandZ is a global var.
*DIVIDE RandZ BY 131072 GIVING rq, RandZ  . Division yields a remainder
*DIVIDE RandZ BY 4 GIVING rq
*SET r0 = +[#,[#],1,1]                    . r0 = argument 'min'
*SET r9 = +[#,[#],1,2]                    . r9 = 'max'
*SET rd = r9 - r0 + 1
*DIVIDE rq BY rd GIVING rq, rr
*SET [#,[#],2,1] TO r0 + rr               . return in 'resultVar'
*ENDDEFINE
```

---

In case anyone cares, the scripting language is SSG (Symbolic Stream Generator) in a UNISYS 2200 mainframe operating system called EXEC 8.

---

On criticality: The app this RNG works in generates test data. It's not encrypting state secrets or the nuclear missile codes. So we're talking about "nice to have" and "best effort" rather than "mission critical." I'd be happy about an improvement but am not looking for the ultimate solution.

Comment: Do you have conditionals?

Comment: You could improve what you have now by running what you have now to generate a seed value.

Comment: @Pubby: Yes, there's IF/THEN/ELSE/ENDIF. I'm gonna update my question to reflect that, thanks!

Comment: @Ramhound: I seed `RandZ` with a system value that gives me elapsed CPU time.

Comment: What if you generate 4 9-bit numbers and then combine them (`result = a1 * 2^0 + a2 * 2^9 + a3 * 2^18 + a3 * 2^27`)? These 9-bit numbers should be generated by LCGs with different periods. If all periods are co-prime and co-prime to 4, the total period should be quite large. Please note that this is just a quick hack, and the resulting random numbers will be far from perfect and have repeating patterns (by construction). But depending on your needs, it might be sufficient, and it should be quite fast.

Comment: @Carsten: You and Dr_Sam had the same idea. Please see my comment to him!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to write a linear congruential random number generator that can never overflow, as Stephen K. Park and and Keith W. Miller [demonstrate](http://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/~irjohnso/coursenotes/ufeen8-15-m/p1192-parkmiller.pdf) in their paper *Random Number Generators: Good Ones Are Hard To Find*:

```
function  Random  :  real; 
                  (*  Integer  Version  2  *) 
const 
  a  =  16807; 
  m  =  2147483647; 
  q  =  127773;  (*  m  div  a  *) 
  r  =  2836;  (*  m  mod  a  *) 
var 
  lo,  hi,  test  :  integer; 
begin 
  hi  :=  seed  div  q; 
  lo  :=  seed  mod  q; 
  test  :=  a  *  lo  -  r  *  hi; 
  if  test  >  0  then 
    seed  :=  test 
  else 
    seed  :=  test  +  m; 
  Random  :=  seed  /  m 
end;
```

Here *m* is 2^31-1, but you could change it to yield 36-bit numbers. The trick is that the seed is split into *hi* and *lo* parts and the final random number is generated by summing the parts.

If you don't like that, I have [lots](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/themes/#Random%20Number%20Generators) of random number generators at my blog. Maybe one of them will do what you want.

Comment: I like this implementation for its overflow-proof-ness! Thank you. I think I'll give this a whirl. If it works as advertised it may allow me to avoid combining 2 or 3 calls to a smaller-range RNG. Also thanks for the links to your blog and the paper - in a pinch I could use one of the many examples the paper gives.

Comment: @CarlSmotricz, there's an excellent discussion and analysis of the [Park-Miller-Carter](http://www.firstpr.com.au/dsp/rand31/) PRNG. Carter's optimization dramatically increases performance, and decreases complexity. The site also discusses extending the idea to 64 bits, allowing the high 28 bits of the output to be discarded for your needs.

Comment: Implemented and working like a charm. I read the article with interest but directly adopted your code from above. Since I don't have good constants for a 36-bit version, I'm using your 32-bit version unchanged. It's all good because I only need 25 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple idea, I don't know if that's really the best: You could have 3 LCGs on 12 bits with recursions

x_i(n) = a x_i(n-1) + p_i (mod 2^{12})

which have different primes p_i. If a is not too large (say 12-bit), this will never overflow. Then, with the 3 12-bit random numbers, you can make a 36-bit random integer:

z(n) = x_0(n) + 2^{12} x_1(n) + 2^{24} x_2(n)

Remark that if the p_i are primes and relatively large, the 3 random generators should be quite independant, so that strategy should be quite ok.

The difficulty is to have a good choice for a.

Anyway, before using it, I guess that it would be better making some tests.

Comment: I wonder if my strange scripting language "does" recursion. I think it does, but because procedures don't return values other than through side effects it might be tricky to code this solution recursively! Still, the basic idea is sound; and if the RNGs have coprime parameters I should get some nice long periods. At the moment, I am generating 2 numbers in the 0..999 range and concatenating them into the 6 digit number I need, which halves my RNG's period but is not a problem. I'm still looking for a more elegant single-call solution though.

Comment: Well, you can implement it as a single recursion with a state composed of 3 12-bit integers or a 36 bit integer (that you decompose), in the same fashion as the other answer. Anyway, the other answer has been tested, so for sure better!